# Should object handle its own actions/logic?

Tags: oop

Basic question is if we should keep logic in "object" classes or in separated services that performs calculations?

Let's have scenario: We have object of type "Polygon" that can be displayed on a Canvas, it can also be merged with other Polygons creating new one that is sum of both. So we should have methods like: 
1. DrawOnCanvas(..) 2. Merge(..)  So the question is should these methods be stored on Polygon class (well DrawOnCanvas could be stored on Canvas class) or on some PolygonService class?
Are there some formalized methodologies that suggests one way over the other?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there some formalized methodologies that suggests one way over the
>   other?

Not at all, but you would call this [*a good separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Some observations:

- An operation like `DrawOnCanvas(...)` wouldn't be of a `Polygon` class, because you want to enforce reusability. That is, a `Polygon` should be usable as a drawable object or just as a regular domain object. I see a `DrawOnCanvas(...)` method as part of a class like `UIRenderer` which would provide an overload to handle instances of `Polygon`.
- `Merge(...)` shouldn't be on `Polygon` because involves two polygons. It's safe to implement it on a `PolygonService`.
- You should implement methods on `Polygon` if these represent an operation that mutates the `Polygon` or only involves a given instance of `Polygon`. For example, `CalculateArea(...)`, `CalculatePerimeter(...)`...

Answer (score 0):

A PolygonService is definitely a bad idea, if only because of the name. You might need an extra class responsible for the interaction between Canvas and Polygon once that becomes of interesting complexity, and that definitely needs a different name, and no mixing with a class responsible for merging and creating new ones.